# Как парсить массив с объектами из файла

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть файл, в котором лежит массив из объектов. Необходимо его обработать так, чтобы массив передался в переменную. Обращаюсь к файлу таким способом:

```
constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    this.state ={
        cards:[]
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    fetch(API_URL+'/cards', {headers:API_HEADERS})
        .then((response)=>response.text())
        .then((responseData) => this.setState({cards:responseData}))
        .catch((err)=>console.log('ERR',err));
}
...
```

в итоге получается просто строка с содержимым этого файла.
файл выглядит так:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    title: 'card1',
    status: 'in-progress',
    description: 'desk1',
    tasks:[{id:1,name:'task1 for card1',done: true},
            {id:2,name:'task2 for card1',done: false},
            {id:3,name:'task3 for card1',done: false}]
  },{
    id: 2,
    title: 'card2',
    status: 'todo',
    description: 'desk2',
    tasks:[]
  }]
```

Как правильно передавать содержимое файла в переменную?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `response.text()` на `response.json()`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тогда обрабатывается catch c таким комментом: "SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern."

Comment: конечно, потому что у вас `JSON` не валидный

Answer (score 1):

У вас возвращается текст, который похож на `js` объект. Но в данном случае, превратить его в настоящий `js` объект вы сможете только с помощью `eval`, что плохо.

Выход один  - в файле должен содержаться `JSON`, что бы его создать, вам нужно заменить все одинарные скобки на двойные + все ключи обернуть двойными скобками

```
[
  {
    "id": 1, // числа можно не оборачивать
    "title": "card1",
    "status": "in-progress",
    // ...
    "tasks": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "task1 for card1",
      "done": true // boolean тоже не нужно оборачивать
    }]
  },
  // ...
]
```

Если сделаете это, то сможете легко получать объект из JSON:

```
// заменив
.then((response)=>response.text())
// на
.then((response)=>response.json())
```

[Здесь можно побаловаться online](https://jsoneditoronline.org)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаток react и серверных javascript технологий, но, все же позволю заметить, с высоты знания ES5.

Исхожу из того, что у нас на руках уже есть строковое содержимое файла в переменной `data`.

На мой взгляд, правильным было бы использовать функцию `JSON.parse(data)`, но содержимое вашего файла не является валидным JSON кодом. Преобразуйте файл в правильный JSON, воспользуйтесь `JSON.parse(data)` и проблема будет решена.
Вот здесь коротко и ясно написано про JSON https://learn.javascript.ru/json.

Если же у вас отсутствует возможность привести файл к надлежащему виду, возможно использование функции `eval(data)`, т.к. ваш файл является валидным JavaScript кодом. Но это решение порекомендовать не могу, т.к. использование `eval()` вызывает у меня легкий приступ паранойи.